# Given a 2-layer GCN, can we choose the dimensions of the 2nd weight matrix, such that this architecture has the same capacity as a 1-layer GCN?

Tags: activation-functions, geometric-deep-learning, hyper-parameters, graph-neural-networks, representation-learning

This might be more of a question about nested function classes:

For $k$ class node classification in a graph with $n$ nodes, and $d$ feature vector.

I want to compare

Architecture I: the GCN model of Kipf/ Welling with two graph convolutional layers:
$$
\mathbf{Y}=\operatorname{softmax}\left(\mathbf{A} \xi\left(\mathbf{A X W}_{1}\right) \mathbf{W}_{2}\right)
$$

where

- $\mathbf{X}$ is $n \times d,
  - $ $\mathbf{Y}$ is $n \times k$
- $\mathbf{A}$ is a fixed $n \times n$ graph diffusion matrix,
- $\mathbf{W}_{1}, \mathbf{W}_{2}$ are learnable weight matrices of size $d \times d^{\prime}$ and $d^{\prime} \times 2,$ respectively, shared across all nodes, and
- $\xi$ is a nonlinearity.

Architecture II: a single-layer graph neural network of the form:
$$
\mathbf{Y}=\operatorname{softmax}\left(\mathbf{A}^{2} \mathbf{X W}\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{W}$ is a learnable weight matrix of size $d \times 2$.

---

Now I'm wondering

- $\operatorname{Can} \xi, d^{\prime}$ be chosen in a way that both architectures have the same expressive power? (i.e. can represent the same class of functions)?
- $\operatorname{Can} \xi, d^{\prime}$ be chosen in a way that Architecture II is more expressive?
- What would be the advantage in training complexity of Architecture II when applied to large-scale graphs.

Comment: Could you please focus on 1 **specific** question (eventually, you can add 1-2 more sub-questions, provided they are sub-questions and not distinct questions)? Then could you please put that specific question in the title? To me, it seems that your questions are quite distinct (and a bit broad) and require a lot of effort to answer properly. So, I actually suggest that you focus on 1 of those questions and remove the others. If you have more questions, ask them in other separate posts.